# Sql select the winner

Tags: sql, oracle

having this database, bold = PK

CERTIFICATE(**USERID**, **CERTIFICATENAME**)

i need to find the userid with the maximum number of certificates with a SQL query.

sample data:

```
USERID, CERTIFICATENAME
1,cert1
1,cert2
1,cert3
2,cert4
2,cert5
3,cert2
4,cert1
```

with this sample data i need a query for find that user:1 has 3 certificates, this user has the maximum number of certificates.

request result:

```
USERID, COUNT
1,3
```

in this case my dbms is oracle, but i'm looking for a generic sql solution to my problem.

Comment: What was wrong with the SQL that you tried, but forgot to share?

Comment: i'm not able to write a query for obtain the requested result :-(

Comment: You might want to start with a `COUNT(CERTIFICATENAME) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using old plain group by:

```
select top 1 userid, count(certificatename) total
from certificates
group by userid -- but not certificatename
order by 2 desc --you can use total or count(certificatname) here
```

Common Table Expressions (CTE) don't add any performance preferences because you need group by in any case.

Answer (score 2):

As a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(Total), UserId FROM -- select the max count
( -- create the counts per user
    SELECT Count(CertificateName) as Total, 
           UserId 
    FROM YourTable 
    GROUP BY CertificateName, UserId
) GROUP BY Total, UserId
```

Comment: my dbms is oracle, your subquery solution sounds good.. i'll try it

Comment: @Yatrix CertificateName in group by results in total is always equals to 1. And you missed group by in outer select in both examples. I do not downvote. Just inform you.